# Interval intersection in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, interval-tree

#### Update 5:

This feature has been released as part of pandas 20.1 (on my birthday :] )

#### Update 4:

PR has been merged!

#### Update 3:

[The PR has moved here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/15309)

#### Update 2:

It seems like this question may have contributed to [re-opening the PR for IntervalIndex in pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/8707#issuecomment-276868158).

### Update:

I no longer have this problem, since I'm actually now querying for overlapping ranges from `A` and `B`, not points from `B` which fall within ranges in `A`, which is a full interval tree problem. I won't delete the question though, because I think it's still a valid question, and I don't have a good answer.

### Problem statement

I have two dataframes.

In dataframe `A`, two of the integer columns taken together represent an interval.

In dataframe `B`, one integer column represents a position.

I'd like to do a sort of join, such that points are assigned to each interval they fall within.

Intervals are rarely but occasionally overlapping. If a point falls within that overlap, it should be assigned to both intervals. About half of points won't fall within an interval, but nearly every interval will have at least one point within its range.

#### What I've been thinking

I was initially going to dump my data out of pandas, and use [intervaltree](https://github.com/chaimleib/intervaltree) or [banyan](https://github.com/cpcloud/banyan) or maybe [bx-python](https://github.com/bxlab/bx-python) but then I came across this [gist](https://gist.github.com/shoyer/c939325f509d7c027949). It turns out that the ideas shoyer has in there never made it into pandas, but it got me thinking -- it might be possible to do this within pandas, and since I want this code to be as fast as python can possibly go, I'd rather not dump my data out of pandas until the very end. I also get the feeling that this is possible with `bins` and pandas [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) function, but I'm a total newbie to pandas, so I could use some guidance! Thanks!

#### Notes

Potentially related? [Pandas DataFrame groupby overlapping intervals of variable length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912524/pandas-dataframe-groupby-overlapping-intervals-of-variable-length)

Comment: You need to post your sample dataframes and sample output desired

Comment: How do I post the dataframe? It's quite wide and tall, and I feel like I've given the important information. The specific names, if you like, are `A.txStart` and `A.txEnd` for the interval and `B.tss` for the point. They're all just fairly big integers.

Comment: Post the absolute minimum data that will yield an answer that will solve your problem. This means you need to create fake data that mimics exactly the situation you are encountering with the minimum number of columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is was released as part of pandas 20.1

Comment: Could you please post a link?

Answer (score 2):

Answer using [pyranges](https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/pyranges), which is basically pandas sprinkled with bioinformatics sugar.

Setup:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
import pyranges as pr

a = pr.random(int(1e6))
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
# | Chromosome   | Start     | End       | Strand       |
# | (category)   | (int32)   | (int32)   | (category)   |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------|
# | chr1         | 8830650   | 8830750   | +            |
# | chr1         | 9564361   | 9564461   | +            |
# | chr1         | 44977425  | 44977525  | +            |
# | chr1         | 239741543 | 239741643 | +            |
# | ...          | ...       | ...       | ...          |
# | chrY         | 29437476  | 29437576  | -            |
# | chrY         | 49995298  | 49995398  | -            |
# | chrY         | 50840129  | 50840229  | -            |
# | chrY         | 38069647  | 38069747  | -            |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
# Stranded PyRanges object has 1,000,000 rows and 4 columns from 25 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome and Strand.

b = pr.random(int(1e6), length=1)
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
# | Chromosome   | Start     | End       | Strand       |
# | (category)   | (int32)   | (int32)   | (category)   |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------|
# | chr1         | 52110394  | 52110395  | +            |
# | chr1         | 122640219 | 122640220 | +            |
# | chr1         | 162690565 | 162690566 | +            |
# | chr1         | 117198743 | 117198744 | +            |
# | ...          | ...       | ...       | ...          |
# | chrY         | 45169886  | 45169887  | -            |
# | chrY         | 38863683  | 38863684  | -            |
# | chrY         | 28592193  | 28592194  | -            |
# | chrY         | 29441949  | 29441950  | -            |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
# Stranded PyRanges object has 1,000,000 rows and 4 columns from 25 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome and Strand.
```

Execution:

```
result = a.join(b, strandedness="same")
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
# | Chromosome   | Start     | End       | Strand       | Start_b   | End_b     | Strand_b     |
# | (category)   | (int32)   | (int32)   | (category)   | (int32)   | (int32)   | (category)   |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------|
# | chr1         | 227348436 | 227348536 | +            | 227348516 | 227348517 | +            |
# | chr1         | 18901135  | 18901235  | +            | 18901191  | 18901192  | +            |
# | chr1         | 230131576 | 230131676 | +            | 230131636 | 230131637 | +            |
# | chr1         | 84829850  | 84829950  | +            | 84829903  | 84829904  | +            |
# | ...          | ...       | ...       | ...          | ...       | ...       | ...          |
# | chrY         | 44139791  | 44139891  | -            | 44139821  | 44139822  | -            |
# | chrY         | 51689785  | 51689885  | -            | 51689859  | 51689860  | -            |
# | chrY         | 45379140  | 45379240  | -            | 45379215  | 45379216  | -            |
# | chrY         | 37469479  | 37469579  | -            | 37469576  | 37469577  | -            |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
# Stranded PyRanges object has 16,153 rows and 7 columns from 24 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome and Strand.

df = result.df
#       Chromosome      Start        End Strand    Start_b      End_b Strand_b
# 0           chr1  227348436  227348536      +  227348516  227348517        +
# 1           chr1   18901135   18901235      +   18901191   18901192        +
# 2           chr1  230131576  230131676      +  230131636  230131637        +
# 3           chr1   84829850   84829950      +   84829903   84829904        +
# 4           chr1  189088140  189088240      +  189088163  189088164        +
# ...          ...        ...        ...    ...        ...        ...      ...
# 16148       chrY   38968068   38968168      -   38968124   38968125        -
# 16149       chrY   44139791   44139891      -   44139821   44139822        -
# 16150       chrY   51689785   51689885      -   51689859   51689860        -
# 16151       chrY   45379140   45379240      -   45379215   45379216        -
# 16152       chrY   37469479   37469579      -   37469576   37469577        -
# 
# [16153 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Although it's not a general solution to OP's question, this seems quite useful for some, like myself :P

Can you give a rough idea of how it works?