# Merge two dataframes based on interval overlap

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

I have two dataframes A and B:

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
In [37]:
A = pd.DataFrame({'Start': [10, 11, 20, 62, 198], 'End': [11, 11, 35, 70, 200]})

A[["Start","End"]]
Out[37]:
Start   End
0   10  11
1   11  11
2   20  35
3   62  70
4   198 200
In [38]:
B = pd.DataFrame({'Start': [8, 5, 8, 60], 'End': [10, 90, 13, 75], 'Info': ['some_info0','some_info1','some_info2','some_info3']})

B[["Start","End","Info"]]
Out[38]:
Start   End Info
0   8   10  some_info0
1   5   90  some_info1
2   8   13  some_info2
3   60  75  some_info3
```

I would like to add column info to dataframe A based on if the interval (Start-End) of A overlaps with the interval of B. In case, the A interval overlaps with more than one B interval, the info corresponding to the shorter interval should be added.

I have been looking arround how to manage this issue and I have found kind of similar questions but most of their answers are using `iterrows()` which in my case, as I am dealing with huge dataframes is not viable.

I would like something like:

```
A.merge(B,on="overlapping_interval", how="left")
```

And then drop duplicates keeping the info coming from the shorter interval.

The output should look like this:

```
In [39]:
C = pd.DataFrame({'Start': [10, 11, 20, 62, 198], 'End': [11, 11, 35, 70, 200], 'Info': ['some_info0','some_info2','some_info1','some_info3',np.nan]})

C[["Start","End","Info"]]
Out[39]:
Start   End Info
0   10  11  some_info0
1   11  11  some_info2
2   20  35  some_info1
3   62  70  some_info3
4   198 200 NaN
```

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983874/interval-intersection-in-pandas) really interesting as it suggests the posibility of solving this issue using pandas Interval object. But after lots attempts I have not managed to solve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: `iterrows` gives a generator so would be a good fit for huge DataFrames. you already tried it ??

Comment: It is not problem of memory but time.

Comment: For now I would write your own algorithm which handles this task. Your first step might be to sort both Dataframes. ---  Btw1: to make your question better I would suggest to give an example of the output ---- Btw2: if you print Dataframes in the console then they will be outlined and look better, the ones in your question are badly outlined.

Comment: @PauRS, can you elaborate on interval edges (left and right) - are they closed/open and please add your desired data set?

Comment: Please post the desired output.

Comment: Thank you all! I have just edited the question. Hope that help you to understand my issue.

Comment: @MaxU the intervals are closed. I have managed to add a new column to A and B dataframes with datatype interval (with apply(lambda row: pd.Interval(left=row.Start, right=row.End, closed="both")). But don't know how to do the merge efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to do a function then apply on the rows:

First I compute the delta (End - Start) in `B` for sorting purpose

```
B['delta'] = B.End - B.Start
```

Then a function to get information:

```
def get_info(x):
    #Fully included
    c0 = (x.Start >= B.Start) & (x.End <= B.End)
    #start lower, end include
    c1 = (x.Start <= B.Start) & (x.End >= B.Start)
    #start include, end higher
    c2 = (x.Start <= B.End) & (x.End >= B.End)

    #filter with conditions and sort by delta
    _B = B[c0|c1|c2].sort_values('delta',ascending=True)

    return None if len(_B) == 0 else _B.iloc[0].Info #None if no info corresponding
```

Then you can apply this function to `A`:

```
A['info'] = A.apply(lambda x : get_info(x), axis='columns')


print(A)
   Start  End        info
0     10   11  some_info0
1     11   11  some_info2
2     20   35  some_info1
3     62   70  some_info3
4    198  200        None
```

Note:

- Instead of using `pd.Interval`, make your own conditions. `cx` are your intervals definitions, change them to get the exact expected behaviour

Comment: Thanks a lot! That looks to be a great solution. Just note a typo: instead of len(_dfb) should be len(_B)

Comment: I will now implement it to my code and check if its really as efficient as it seems to be. I will let you know :)

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I had to rename after you put the samples. Let me know if it fits your pb.

Comment: As expected, super efficient. It lasted about 5 minutes (A has 120,000 rows and B 400,000 rows). Really appreciate your help!!