# How to efficiently join two dataframes if they have overlapping intervals?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have two dataframes:

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'start_date':['2022-07-01 00:02:41','2022-07-01 00:07:41','2022-07-01 00:22:41','2022-07-01 01:01:23','2022-07-01 01:01:23'],'end_date':['2022-07-01 00:02:41','2022-07-01 00:17:41','2022-07-01 00:57:42','2022-07-01 01:01:23','2022-07-01 01:03:51',], 'eventname':['e2','e3','e5','e6','e7',] })
df_B = pd.DataFrame({'start_date':['2022-07-01 00:00:41','2022-07-01 00:06:41','2022-07-01 00:17:56','2022-07-01 01:03:40',],'end_date':['2022-07-01 00:01:41','2022-07-01 00:14:41','2022-07-01 00:19:42','2022-07-01 02:03:23',], 'eventname':['e1','e3','e4','e7',] })

#df_A
    start_date          end_date            eventname
0   2022-07-01 00:02:41 2022-07-01 00:02:41 e2
1   2022-07-01 00:07:41 2022-07-01 00:17:41 e3
2   2022-07-01 00:22:41 2022-07-01 00:57:42 e5
3   2022-07-01 01:01:23 2022-07-01 01:01:23 e6
4   2022-07-01 01:01:23 2022-07-01 01:03:51 e7


#df_B
    start_date          end_date            eventname
0   2022-07-01 00:00:41 2022-07-01 00:01:41 e1
1   2022-07-01 00:06:41 2022-07-01 00:14:41 e3
2   2022-07-01 00:17:56 2022-07-01 00:19:42 e4
3   2022-07-01 01:03:40 2022-07-01 02:03:23 e7
```

I would like to join the rows of df_B to df_A if the time interval has any overlap and my expected result is this:

```
df_C = pd.DataFrame({'start_date_A':['nan','2022-07-01 00:02:41','2022-07-01 00:07:41','nan','2022-07-01 00:22:41','2022-07-01 01:01:23','2022-07-01 01:01:23',],'end_date_A':['nan','2022-07-01 00:02:41', '2022-07-01 00:17:41','nan','2022-07-01 00:57:42','2022-07-01 01:01:23','2022-07-01 01:03:51',],'start_date_b':['2022-07-01 00:00:41','nan','2022-07-01 00:06:41','2022-07-01 00:17:56','nan','nan','2022-07-01 01:03:40',],'end_date_b':['2022-07-01 00:01:41', 'nan', '2022-07-01 00:14:41', '2022-07-01 00:19:42', 'nan', 'nan', '2022-07-01 02:03:23', ], 'eventname':['e2','e1','e3','e4','e5','e6','e7']  })

#df_C
```

[image]

I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48168292/merge-two-dataframes-based-on-interval-overlap) but it gives me only the first value of the column each time, not the value for that row.

I also tried using the IntervalIndex like this:

```
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_A['start_date'], 
                                    df_A['end_date'],
                                    closed='both')

out = df_B.assign(interval=pd.cut(df_B['eventname'], bins)) \
          .merge(df_A.assign(interval=bins), on='interval', how='left')
```

but I get the error that overlapping intervals are not allowed. How can I do this?

**Edit:** eventname also need to be the same for the join to happen. If not, both the rows have to be present separately so it will be a full join

Comment: Do event names also need to be the same for the join to happen? Which one do you keep if not?

Comment: Yes event names also need to be the same for the join to happen. If not, both the rows have to be present separately so it will be a full join

Comment: In this case you can first join on event name and then split the row if intervals do not overlap (I would try with `explode()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it.

```py
# first, make sure we have Timestamps
for df in [df_A, df_B]:
    for k in ['start_date', 'end_date']:
        df[k] = pd.to_datetime(df[k])

# next, merge on eventname, regardless of interval overlapping
zo = df_A.merge(df_B, on='eventname', suffixes=['_a', '_b'], how='outer')

# finally, transform that result to dissociate non-overlapping groups
def proc(g):
    assert len(g) == 1
    r = g.squeeze()
    try:
        a = pd.Interval(r['start_date_a'], r['end_date_a'])
        b = pd.Interval(r['start_date_b'], r['end_date_b'])
        if a.overlaps(b):
            return g
        # emit two rows instead
        cols = ['start_date_a', 'end_date_a', 'eventname', 'start_date_b', 'end_date_b']
        sa, ea, ev, sb, eb = r[cols]
        return pd.DataFrame([
            [pd.NaT, pd.NaT, ev, sb, eb],
            [sa, ea, ev, pd.NaT, pd.NaT],
        ], columns=cols)
    except ValueError:
        return g

out = zo.groupby(level=0).apply(proc).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Test on OP's data, adding an `eventname='e8'` with non-overlapping intervals to demo what happens then:

```py
df_A = pd.DataFrame({
    'start_date': [
        '2022-07-01 00:02:41', '2022-07-01 00:07:41', '2022-07-01 00:22:41',
        '2022-07-01 01:01:23', '2022-07-01 01:01:23', '2000-01-01'],
    'end_date': [
        '2022-07-01 00:02:41', '2022-07-01 00:17:41', '2022-07-01 00:57:42',
        '2022-07-01 01:01:23', '2022-07-01 01:03:51', '2000-01-02'],
    'eventname': ['e2', 'e3', 'e5', 'e6', 'e7', 'e8'],
})
df_B = pd.DataFrame({
    'start_date': [
        '2022-07-01 00:00:41', '2022-07-01 00:06:41', '2022-07-01 00:17:56',
        '2022-07-01 01:03:40', '2001-01-01'],
    'end_date': [
        '2022-07-01 00:01:41', '2022-07-01 00:14:41', '2022-07-01 00:19:42',
        '2022-07-01 02:03:23', '2001-01-02'],
    'eventname': ['e1', 'e3', 'e4', 'e7', 'e8'],
})

# code above (including pd.to_datetime)

>>> out
  start_date_a        end_date_a          eventname start_date_b        end_date_b         
0 2022-07-01 00:02:41 2022-07-01 00:02:41  e2                       NaT                 NaT
1 2022-07-01 00:07:41 2022-07-01 00:17:41  e3       2022-07-01 00:06:41 2022-07-01 00:14:41
2 2022-07-01 00:22:41 2022-07-01 00:57:42  e5                       NaT                 NaT
3 2022-07-01 01:01:23 2022-07-01 01:01:23  e6                       NaT                 NaT
4 2022-07-01 01:01:23 2022-07-01 01:03:51  e7       2022-07-01 01:03:40 2022-07-01 02:03:23
5                 NaT                 NaT  e8       2001-01-01 00:00:00 2001-01-02 00:00:00
6 2000-01-01 00:00:00 2000-01-02 00:00:00  e8                       NaT                 NaT
7                 NaT                 NaT  e1       2022-07-01 00:00:41 2022-07-01 00:01:41
8                 NaT                 NaT  e4       2022-07-01 00:17:56 2022-07-01 00:19:42
```

#### Another way to dissociate rows with non-overlapping intervals

We can also use some numpy tricks to quickly repeat rows that should be dissociated and then selectively null out `a` or `b` dates in those rows:

```py
# starting from zo as above:
zo = df_A.merge(df_B, on='eventname', suffixes=['_a', '_b'], how='outer')

acols = ['start_date_a', 'end_date_a']
bcols = ['start_date_b', 'end_date_b']

mask = ~zo[acols + bcols].isna().any(axis=1).values
ov = zo.loc[mask].apply(
    lambda r: pd.Interval(*r[acols]).overlaps(pd.Interval(*r[bcols])),
    axis=1).values
mask[mask] &= ~ov
```

Now, `mask` contains `True` only where `zo` rows should be dissociated:

```py
>>> zo.loc[mask]
  start_date_a end_date_a eventname start_date_b end_date_b
5 2000-01-01   2000-01-02  e8       2001-01-01   2001-01-02
```

Now we use some `numpy` functions to achieve duplication of the rows to dissociate, and `anull` and `bnull` arrays to indicate where to blank out the result:

```py
sel = np.repeat(np.arange(len(zo)), mask + 1)
anull = np.r_[np.diff(sel), 1] == 0
bnull = np.r_[1, np.diff(sel)] == 0

>>> sel
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7])

>>> anull
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False])

>>> bnull
array([False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False])

out = zo.iloc[sel].reset_index(drop=True)
out.loc[anull, acols] = pd.NaT
out.loc[bnull, bcols] = pd.NaT

>>> out
# same as above
```

Comment: Can you explain why you convert it to a series and then take the Interval? And also, why do you group by the index?

Comment: `groupby` on the index ensures that `proc` is applied on each group of 1 row. That's similar to `zo.apply(proc, axis=1)`, but `groupby().apply()` is more lenient with the result being in 2D (which is what we have: either the group itself, which is a `DataFrame` of 1 row, for unchanged rows, or a new `DataFrame`, for dissociated rows). We use `Interval` because of its well-defined and strict check for overlapping (less error-prone than coming up with our own check).

Comment: I added a more direct way (using `numpy`) to dissociate rows with no overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Do full join on `eventname` and then split rows where time intervals do not overlap:

```
df_A.start_date = pd.to_datetime(df_A.start_date)
df_A.end_date = pd.to_datetime(df_A.end_date)
df_B.start_date = pd.to_datetime(df_B.start_date)
df_B.end_date = pd.to_datetime(df_B.end_date)

df = df_A.set_index("eventname").join(df_B.set_index("eventname"), how="outer", lsuffix="_a", rsuffix="_b")


def overlap_processing(row: pd.Series):
    if (
        (row.start_date_a <= row.start_date_b <= row.end_date_a)
        or (row.start_date_a <= row.end_date_b <= row.end_date_a)
        or row.isna().any()
    ):
        return row
    else:
        return pd.Series(
            {
                "start_date_a": [row.start_date_a, pd.NaT],
                "end_date_a": [row.end_date_a, pd.NaT],
                "start_date_b": [pd.NaT, row.start_date_b],
                "end_date_b": [pd.NaT, row.end_date_b],
            }
        )


result = df.apply(overlap_processing, axis=1).explode(list(df.columns)).reset_index()
```

Comment: I get the wrong result with your code but I can't figure out why. Why do you use the explode() function?

Comment: From how I understood your problem, you have 1 row for each event in both tables. If the intervals for specific event overlap, you want to have a single output row, otherwise 2 output rows (where some values are NaT. `explode()` just splits 1 row into 2 in this case.