# Left join of date with start and end date of another table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Below first two table is `cat1` and `cat2` table
basically, I hope to left join `cat1` with `cat2`, where `cat1` date is between start/end date of `cat2`.
Last table is the outcome, how should I achieve this efficiently? Note that I have 100k records in real table.
Btw, If we have Date of `cat1` falling in two StartDate & EndDate (two rows of `cat2`), then it will ended up having two rows in the output table.

[image]

Please find the code below for `cat1` and `cat2`

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

cat1=pd.DataFrame({
    "CatID":[1, 2, 3],
    "Date":[date(2019,10,1), date(2019,11,1), date(2019,12,1)]
})

cat2=pd.DataFrame({
    "Interesting":[1, 2, 3,4],
    "StartDate":[date(2019,10,1), date(2019,11,1),date(2019,11,1), date(2018,10,6)],
    "EndDate":[date(2019,10,30), date(2019,11,30),date(2019,11,30), date(2018,10,6)]
})
```

I have tried the solution here
[How to merge two dataframe with column in overlapping datetime range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155328/how-to-merge-two-dataframe-with-column-in-overlapping-datetime-range)

```
# df2[["start"]] is a column vector of size m and df1.timestamp.values is row 
## vector of size n then broad cast will result matrix of shape m,n which is 
## result of comparing each pair of m and n
compare = (cat2[["StartDate"]].values<=cat1.Date.values) & (cat2[["EndDate"]].values>=cat1.Date.values)

## get cell numbers which is in range 0 to matrix size which meets the condition
ind = np.arange(len(cat1)*len(cat2))[compare.ravel()]


## calculate row and column index from cell number
pd.concat([cat2.iloc[ind//len(cat1)].reset_index(drop=True), cat1.iloc[ind%len(cat1)].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1, sort=False)
```

Which I got

[image]

it is not what I want, as it lacks of the last row (as what I need is left join).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cross join and `series.between()`:

```
#convert to datetime
cat1['Date']=pd.to_datetime(cat1['Date'])

cat2[['StartDate','EndDate']]=cat2[['StartDate','EndDate']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

---

```
m=cat1.assign(k=1).merge(cat2.assign(k=1)).drop('k',1)
final=(m[m.Date.between(m.StartDate,m.EndDate)]
  .merge(cat1,on=['Date','CatID'],how='right').drop(['StartDate','EndDate'],1))
```

---

```
   CatID       Date  Interesting
0      1 2019-10-01          1.0
1      2 2019-11-01          2.0
2      2 2019-11-01          3.0
3      3 2019-12-01          NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution with two rows in cat2 that matched in cat1, and it throws error, please find the code above in the question.

Comment: @william007 yes because of the duplicate date range, what would be your expected output here(since you have 2 same date range with different `Interesting` number )? can you update the question as well, thanks

Comment: Hi anky_91, I have updated the questions with desired output.

Comment: @william007 I have updated my answer. though it may be a little slow, but can you test please? thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you produced is an 'inner' join. Build the right columns as a separate data frame before you concat them. Make sure that the number of rows are equal.

```
# df2[["start"]] is a column vector of size m and df1.timestamp.values is row 
## vector of size n then broad cast will result matrix of shape m,n which is 
## result of comparing each pair of m and n
compare = (cat2[["StartDate"]].values<=cat1.Date.values) & (cat2[["EndDate"]].values>=cat1.Date.values)


## get cell numbers which is in range 0 to matrix size which meets the condition
ind_old = np.arange(len(cat1)*len(cat2))[compare.ravel()]
ind_new = np.arange(len(cat1)*len(cat2))[compare.T.ravel()]
cat1_new = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=list(cat2.index), columns=cat1.columns)

## match the rows of cat1 to those of cat2
cat1_new.iloc[ind_new%len(cat2)] = cat1.iloc[ind_old%len(cat1)].reset_index(drop=True)


## calculate row and column index from cell number
print(pd.concat([cat2, cat1_new], axis=1, sort=False))

## concat 
print(pd.concat([cat2, cat1_new], axis=1, sort=False))

#    Interesting   StartDate     EndDate  CatID        Date
# 0            1  2019-10-01  2019-10-30    1.0  2019-10-01
# 1            2  2019-11-01  2019-11-30    2.0  2019-11-01
# 2            3  2019-11-01  2019-11-30    2.0  2019-11-01
# 3            4  2018-10-06  2018-10-06    NaN         NaN
```